# Minimize ssh windows when Eclipse retrieves info from svn repository

Tags: eclipse, windows-xp, cygwin, subclipse

I'm running Eclipse Indigo on Windows XP & Cygwin using the Subclipse plugin with our corporation SVN repository.

Overall it works just fine, however whenever I click on a file in the remote SVN repository a half dozen cmd windows open for the various ssh processes Subclipse spawns using Cygwin's ssh executable.  This is very annoying since they pop up directly in front of what I'm working on and steal the cursor focus.

Could anyone tell me how I can insure that when these windows are spawned they're minimized so that they don't interfere?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a GUI SSH client like TortoisePlink which comes with TortoiseSVN.  I believe the other option would be to start Eclipse from your Cygwin Terminal.  I believe the SSH client will then be connected with that Terminal and not spawn any additional windows.